# Do I need to use mutex on concurreny reading, but not writing

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

Example:

```
func NewExample() *Example {
    return &Example{}
}

type Example struct {
    foo bool
}

func (e *Example) Start(ctx context.Context) {
    go func() {
        ticker := timer.NewTicker(time.Second)
        // this goroutine listens for ticker and might change the foo value of the struct
    }()
}

func (e *Example) GetFoo() bool {
    return e.foo
}
```

Should the Example.foo variable be under the mutex if the reading is done by multiple goroutines, but writing is from one goroutine only?  Please, explain why

What's the difference between using RWMutex to access/modify Example.foo and making the Example.foo of type atomic.Bool ?

Comment: If there's a goroutine that writes, you **always** need to synchronize, given that this happens _concurrently_ with the reads. If you only ever write _once_, and only read _after_ that (in the _concurrency_ sense), no synchronization is needed. Run the race detector to detect unsynchronized accesses.

Comment: Atomic is sufficient if I understand your problem. Doc says: *In the terminology of the Go memory model, if the effect of an atomic operation A is observed by atomic operation B, then A “synchronizes before” B. Additionally, all the atomic operations executed in a program behave as though executed in some sequentially consistent order. This definition provides the same semantics as C++'s sequentially consistent atomics and Java's volatile variables.* Without more context, hard to answer.

Comment: Well, icza actually nailed it but I'd say the example is not complete to it's hardly possible to verify whether the text of your answer matches your code. The problem is that GetFoo is not called anywhere. If we assume you meant that NewExample is called and then Start is called on the returned value and then GetFoo is called _while_ the goroutine started by Start is working, then yes: you have a classical data race because reading in GetFoo might occur simultaneously with writing in that anonymous goroutine started by Start.

Comment: Jean-Baptiste is correct in that in this toy example atomic access is enough but I would highly advise to not follow thier piece of advise _yet:_ before you understand the concurrency matters better. Atomic access is good for speeding up things, and you're clearly not there yet: as of now, you should concentrate on making your code correct and easy to read (for others, and future you).

Comment: Sorry for the poor example. `Example` struct is a singletone, means it created once on app startup. `Example.Start` also called once, on app startup, but the goroutine that `Start` method invokes might change the `Example.Foo` value. 
Application is an API. So on every hit I have to call `GetFoo` function. There is only one goroutine writing the value, but many that call `GetFoo`.
The question is should I use `atomic.Bool` and `e.foo.Load()` to read and `e.foo.Store(value)` to update, or should I use `sync.Mutex` and `e.mu.Lock/Unlock` to sync the access to the `foo` field

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `atomic.Bool` and a mutex is simple: the `atomic.Bool` type is inherently *atomic* meaning that it's impossible for a read to occur simultaneously with a write. As its name suggests, any operation is atomic, meaning changing the value, or reading it looks like it essentially is a single instruction on the lowest level. A mutex on the other hand is an external type that you add to/associate with a type and allows you to lock something for however long you want/need it to be locked. Think of a mutex like a DB transaction: you get some state, lock it in that state, operate on it (no mater how many operations it takes), and at the end you release the lock (which is analogous to committing your DB transaction). A mutex can be applied to more than a single field in a single struct. It's more powerful in the sense that it can handle more complex types, and be applied to more variables/fields over a longer period of time, but for the simplified example you gave, it doesn't really add much value

---

Considering you state that you're going to be reading the field concurrently, the same kind of applies to your writes. Sure there may only be 1 actual routine writing values to the field, but from the viewpoint of the reading routines, that really doesn't matter. Arguably, this is kind of like the equivalence principle in relativity. The reading routine doesn't care where the writes come from, whether there's 1 or more routine writing. What matters is that the writes and reads can occur concurrently. However, if you want to allow 100 concurrent reads (which is perfectly valid), and especially if you're dealing with more complex types that can't really be covered by a simple `atomic.T` type, then a mutex (or RWMutex) is the way to go:

```
type Example struct {
    rmu *sync.RWMutex
    foo bool
}

func (e *Example) SetFoo(f bool) {
    e.rmu.Lock() // read-write lock: no other writes or read are allowed
    e.foo = f
    e.rmu.Unlock()
}

func (e *Example) GetFoo() bool {
    e.rmu.RLock() // read lock: concurrent reads are allowed, no writes can occur
    defer e.rmu.RUnlock() // release read lock
    return e.foo
}
```

Comment: @icza right you are, I suspect I tripped myself up by thinking about a channel-based approach here that just was a bit too much of a faff to write up here. Updated the answer